# How to turn .txt files uploaded with paperclip into raw text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I added a `document` column to my `Post` model, so now I'm able to add `txt` files to it:

**post.rb:**

```
has_attached_file :document
validates_attachment_content_type :document, :content_type => 'text/plain'
```

**console:**

```
 #<Post id: 92, content: "document upload test", user_id: 1, created_at: "2013-01-02 10:23:13", updated_at: "2013-01-02 10:23:13",
 title: "document upload test", document_file_name: "test.txt",
 document_content_type: "text/plain", document_file_size: 15,
 document_updated_at: "2013-01-02 10:23:13">
```

So now, I would like to turn the content inside `test.txt` into raw text. So I can do something like this in my controller:

`@post.content = [TEXT INSIDE test.txt]`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a [before_save callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks), then find the path, open the file and call `File::read` on the opened file.

```
class Post
  before_save :contents_of_file_into_body

  private
  def contents_of_file_into_body
    path = document.queued_for_write[:original].path
    content = File.open(path).read
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried that in the console, but I'm getting this: `post.document.read.strip
NoMethodError: undefined method `read' for /system/posts/documents/000/000/092/original/test.txt?1357122193:Paperclip::Attachment`

Comment: I updated the question after example at [the wiki](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Extracting-mp3-metadata). File needs opening before it can be read.

Comment: Thanks! it worked (but had to change `@post.content` to `self.content`).

Comment: sounds really ugly, should live in a processor. Or at least, add a condition to avoid to do this on each save

Comment: apneadiving: it *is* ugly, but simply starting point; one that answers the exact questions, not most imaginary edge-cases :). Yes, conditionals are needed when stuff gets more complicated (or tests dictate so). For now, there is too little context (maybe text-file is ensured to be there always?) to write the cleanest solution ever.